# Android app launching the browser instead of the app

Tags: android, webview, android-tabhost

I created a TabHost android app with 5 tabs, all of which use a webview for the content (some local some www). It all runs smoothly, but when the app first launches, the browser launches with one of the sites meant to load in a webview for one of the tabs. Pressing the back button closes the browser and brings you to the app itself. Any ideas why it does this?

All of my tabs have the same basic code:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TabHost tabHost=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        tabHost.setup();


        TabSpec spec1=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 1");
        spec1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        spec1.setIndicator("Start",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_start_selected));
        WebView start = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview); 
        start.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/start.html");
```

With the main.xml file like this:

```
<TabHost android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/tabHost"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<TabWidget
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@android:id/tabs"
/>
 <FrameLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"

 >
 <LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/tab1"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="60px"
 >
 <WebView  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>    

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas why it does this?

Yes - because you are explicitly creating a 'full screen' instance of a `WebView` which is separate from your Activity / TabHost and the Tab contents using this code...

```
WebView start = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview); 
start.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/start.html");
```

...comment those two lines out and see what happens.